# Can you disable notifications on ubuntu one sync?

Tags: ubuntu-one

In Natty, ubuntu one gives a notification every time it syncs, and I have my empathy logs synced, so now every time I write or recive an IM I get a notification that the logs have been synced. Is it possible to turn that off, just for ubuntu one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can disable the notifications from the Ubuntu One control panel. Depending on your version, that is either in the Devices tab or the Settings tab.

If using the old, GTK-based control panel, it's in the Devices tab: [image: Ubuntu One control panel (GTK version) devices tab]

If you’re using the new, QT-based control panel, then it’s in the Settings tab: [image: Ubuntu One control panel (QT version) settings tab]